# Node validator could be found for constraints 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' for FLOAT

Tags: java, spring-boot, floating-point

Posting this because I haven't seen a post relating to FLOAT types on this issue.

`No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.Float'. Check configuration for 'numIngredient'`

How do I change constraints to apply for FLOAT types?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pantry")
public class Pantry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "userID", nullable = false)
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name = "ingredients_in_pantry", nullable = true)
    private String ingredientID;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "number_of_ingredients", nullable = true)
    private Float numIngredient;

    //description of pantry (home, office, kitchen, grandmas, etc.)
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true)
    private String description;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) - `@Size` is supported for CharSequence, Collections, Maps, Arrays. The annotations for numeric types(`@Min`, `@Max`, etc.) do not support double and float, because of rounding errors, citating javadoc - `Note that double and float are not supported due to rounding errors (some providers might provide some approximative support).` Depending on your provider, they might work, or might not.

Your options are:

1. using `BigDecimal` - annotations for validation of numerics support it.
2. write your own custom annotation and validator for double and float - you can use this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator), if you don't know how to.